# Marker API's for gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, coffeescript, gmaps4rails2

Pardon me ,I am asking this question may be because, am not that comfortable with coffee script.
In the latest gmaps4rails, do we have any direct api's to modify the markers after building the map and markers, instead of using the functions you specified in the coffee script in the https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Change-handler-behavior

I mean if we want to dynamically change the marker, like changing the marker to a transparent circle which shows the proximity.

Is there any problem with below code. Does indentation matters?

```
class RichMarkerBuilder extends Gmaps.Google.Builders.Marker #inherit from builtin builder
  #override create_marker method
  create_marker: ->
    options = _.extend @marker_options(), @rich_marker_options()
    @serviceObject = new RichMarker options #assign marker to @serviceObject

  rich_marker_options: ->
    boxText = document.createElement("p")
    boxText.setAttribute("class", 'heat-map-eclipse')
    _.extend(@marker_options(), { content: boxText, flat: true })

@buldMap= (markers)->

 handler = Gmaps.build 'Google', { builders: { Marker: RichMarkerBuilder} } #dependency injection

 #then standard use
 handler.buildMap { provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'} }, ->
   markers = handler.addMarkers(markers)
   handler.bounds.extendWith(markers)
   handler.fitMapToBounds()
```

Comment: dont understand, show some code, how would you transform a marker into a circle?

Comment: I used the same code in  https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Change-handler-behavior  only extra change added is in marker.innerHTML = '<p class="heat-map-eclipse"></p>' .heat-map-eclipse{
    background-color:#a07;
    opacity:0.1;
    width: 200px;
 height: 100px;
 -moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
 border-radius: 100px / 50px;
}   ,But map is comming as empty.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried:

```
class MarkerBuilder extends Gmaps.Google.Builders.Marker

  create_marker: ->
    options = _.extend @marker_options(), @rich_marker_options()
    @serviceObject = new RichMarker options

  rich_marker_options: ->
    boxText = document.createElement("p")
    boxText.setAttribute("class", 'heat-map-eclipse')
    _.extend(@marker_options(), { content: boxText, flat: true })
```

And it gives me:

[image]

So I guess it works out of the box, right?

But you have a wrong approach: markers, by definition always keep the same dimensions

Comment: ? I dont understand your question. Is it a question?

Comment: I was not able to paste the code ...so I updated in the first question itself

Comment: map is not comming..It is comming as empty. To debug, i tried converting coffeescript to js and tried setting debug point ..but control is not comming in buildMap function itself. However if I remove the class extension part control is comming inside buildMap func

Comment: I cant know what you do or not, you;ll have to double check your own code: I cant guess. Or maybe `@buldMap` isnt it supposed to be `@buildMap`?

Comment: I was using the same name in view (buldMap)